# Is there available any flutter plugin which control media volume of device in working on Android and iOS both?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am Finding media volume controller plugin in flutter which works on android device and as well as iOS devices.

I already tried below plugins.

https://pub.dev/packages/volume

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound

https://pub.dev/packages/system_shortcuts

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_volume

those above all plugin not supported on iOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS you need to add a usage description to info.plist:

```
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>This sample uses the microphone to record your speech and convert it to text.</string>
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>audio</string>
</array>
```

Comment: i already try this and after this line adding in info.plist then command run flutter run in iOS device getting error =>linker command failed with exit code 1 .Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

Answer (score 0):

Use [volume_controller](https://pub.dev/packages/volume_controller) plugin. Create an instance of the **VolumeController** class and use it as you wish.

```dart
void main() async {
  var controller = VolumeController();

  controller.setVolume(5);

  var currentVolume = await controller.getVolume();
}
```